# Uninstalling ubuntu from one hard drive and installing on another

Tags: system-installation

I currently have ubuntu installed on a hard drive which already had windows and now I've installed a slave drive I was wondering how to remove or at least move ubuntu onto the other drive so one drive is windows and the other is Windows XP

Answer (score 1):

Copy the partitions over to the other disk.  Boot.  Update-grub so it sees both as bootable.  Fix your fstab on the second one.  Make sure it's only using the second disk with df.  Once it's working delete the old partitions.

Answer (score -1):

use a tool called a remastersys to backup ur existing system and create a bootable iso which u can put it into a usb and re install with all your settings and file restored...

PS clean up your home congaing personal files to make iso smaller